# filter object at python 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, stop-words

In **python 3.X**, I've been writing these codes :

One function for "text_tokenizing" and another one for "remove extra characters". 
In "remove_characters_after_tokenization" function I used "filter".

My problem: When I run my project I see this line in console :

```
<filter object at 0x00000277AA20DE48> <filter object at 0x00000277AA44D160> <filter object at 0x00000277AA44D470>
```

How can I solve this issue?

This is my project's code :

```
import nltk
import re
import string
from pprint import pprint

corpus = ["The brown fox wasn't that quick and he couldn't win the race",
          "Hey that's a great deal! I just bought a phone for $199",
          "@@You'll (learn) a **lot** in the book. Python is an amazing language !@@"]



# Declare a function for "Tokenizing Text"
def tokenize_text(text):
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
    word_tokens = [ nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
    return word_tokens

# Declare a function for "Removing Special Characters"
def remove_characters_after_tokenization(tokens):
    pattern = re.compile('[{}]'.format(re.escape(string.punctuation)))
    filtered_tokens = list(filter(None, [pattern.sub('', token) for token in tokens]))
    return filtered_tokens


token_list = [tokenize_text(text) for text in corpus]
pprint(token_list)

filtered_list_1 = list(filter(None,[remove_characters_after_tokenization(tokens)
                                for tokens in sentence_tokens])
                   for sentence_tokens in token_list)

print(type(filtered_list_1))
print(len(filtered_list_1))
print(filtered_list_1)
```

Comment: @JETM, Thanks for your reply, but how can I check this duplication if exists?

Comment: The culprit is the line where you create filtered_list_1. This line iterates over token_list, not over the iterator returned by filter, so the filter iterator is left uniterated.

Comment: @brelian Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking? That's a comment SO auto-inserts when someone flags as a duplicate. It basically means I thought that person had the same issue you do.

Comment: @JETM Okay, No problem. Actually  I had to create a filter for each sentence_tokens in token_list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line creates a *filter* for each 
*sentence_tokens* in *token_list*:

```
filtered_list_1 = list(filter(None, [remove_characters_after_tokenization(tokens)
                                for tokens in sentence_tokens])
                   for sentence_tokens in token_list)
```

Perhaps you wanted to create a list of lists:

```
filtered_list_1 = list(filter(None, ([remove_characters_after_tokenization(tokens)
                                      for tokens in sentence_tokens]
                                     for sentence_tokens in token_list)))
```

Comment: It works. Thank's for your help.
Exactly I had to filter domain. ;)